# Implementing HuggingFace BERT using tensorflow fro sentence classification

Tags: tensorflow, text-classification, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I am trying to train a model for real disaster tweets prediction(Kaggle Competition) using the Hugging face bert model for classification of the tweets.

I have followed many tutorials and have used many models of bert but none could run in COlab and thros the error

My Code is:

```
!pip install transformers
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from transformers import DistilBertTokenizer, RobertaTokenizer


train = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/My Drive/Kaggle_disaster/train.csv")
test = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/My Drive/Kaggle_disaster/test.csv")


roberta = 'distilbert-base-uncased'
tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained(roberta, do_lower_case = True, add_special_tokens = True, max_length = 128, pad_to_max_length = True)


def tokenize(sentences, tokenizer):
  input_ids, input_masks, input_segments = [], [], []
  for sentence in sentences:
    inputs = tokenizer.encode_plus(sentence, add_special_tokens = True, max_length = 128, pad_to_max_length = True, return_attention_mask = True, return_token_type_ids = True)
    input_ids.append(inputs['input_ids'])
    input_masks.append(inputs['attention_mask'])
    input_segments.append(inputs['token_type_ids'])
  return np.asarray(input_ids, dtype = "int32"), np.asarray(input_masks, dtype = "int32"), np.asarray(input_segments, dtype = "int32")


input_ids, input_masks, input_segments = tokenize(train.text.values, tokenizer)

from transformers import TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification, DistilBertConfig, TFDistilBertModel

distil_bert = 'distilbert-base-uncased'

config = DistilBertConfig(dropout=0.2, attention_dropout=0.2)
config.output_hidden_states = False
transformer_model = TFDistilBertModel.from_pretrained(distil_bert, config = config)

input_ids_in = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(128,), name='input_token', dtype=tf.int32)
input_masks_in = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(128,), name='masked_token', dtype=tf.int32) 
embedding_layer = transformer_model(input_ids_in, attention_mask=input_masks_in)[0]
X = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1))(embedding_layer)
X = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool1D()(X)
X = tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='relu')(X)
X = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(X)
X = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(X)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_ids_in, input_masks_in], outputs = X)
model.compile(Adam(lr = 1e-5), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
for layer in model.layers[:3]:
  layer.trainable = False

bert_input = [
    input_ids,
    input_masks
]


checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('/content/drive/My Drive/disaster_model/model_hugging_face.h5', monitor = 'val_loss', save_best_only= True)


train_history = model.fit(
    bert_input,
    validation_split = 0.2,
    batch_size = 16,
    epochs = 10,
    callbacks = [checkpoint]
)
```

On running the above code in colab I get the following error:

```
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-9df711c91040> in <module>()
      9     batch_size = 16,
     10     epochs = 10,
---> 11     callbacks = [checkpoint]
     12 )

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    966           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    967             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 968               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    969             else:
    970               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:571 train_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:541 train_step  **
        self.trainable_variables)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1804 _minimize
        trainable_variables))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:521 _aggregate_gradients
        filtered_grads_and_vars = _filter_grads(grads_and_vars)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:1219 _filter_grads
        ([v.name for _, v in grads_and_vars],))

    ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['tf_distil_bert_model_23/distilbert/embeddings/word_embeddings/weight:0', 'tf_distil_bert_model_23/distilbert/embeddings/position_embeddings/embeddings:0', 'tf_distil_bert_model_23/distilbert/embeddings/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_distil_bert_model_23/distilbert/embeddings/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_distil_bert_model_23/distilbert/transformer/layer_._0/attention/q_lin/kernel:0', 'tf_distil_bert_model_23/distilbert/transformer/layer_._0/attention/q_lin/bias:0', 'tf_distil_bert_model_23/distilbert/transformer/layer_._0/attention/k_lin/kernel:0', 'tf_distil_bert_model_23/distilbert/transformer/layer_._0/attention/k_lin/bias:0', 'tf_distil_bert_model_23/distilbert/transformer/layer_._0/attention/v_lin/kernel:0', 'tf_distil_bert_model_23/distilbert/transformer/layer_._0/attention/v_lin/bias:0', 'tf_distil_bert_model_23/distilbert/transformer/layer_._0/attention/out_lin/kernel:0', 'tf_distil_bert_model_23/distilbert/transformer/layer_._0/attention/out_lin/bias:0', 'tf_distil_bert_model_23/distilbert/transformer/layer_._0/sa_layer_norm/gamma:0', 'tf_distil_bert_model_23/distilbert/transformer/layer_._0/sa_layer_norm/beta:0', 'tf_distil_bert_model_23/distilbert/transformer/layer_._0/ffn/lin1/kernel:0', 'tf_distil_bert_model_23/distilbert/transformer/layer_._0/ffn/lin1/bias:0', 'tf_distil_bert_model_23/distilbert/transformer/layer_._0/ffn/lin2/kernel:0', 'tf_distil_bert_model_23/distilbert/transformer/layer_._0/ffn/lin2/bias:0', 'tf_...
```

Comment: in fit... I don't see your target... model.fit(X, y)

Comment: Thanks for helping! After passing the label data, I am facing a new error

Comment: Epoch 1/10
381/381 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4822 - accuracy: 0.7778
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-33efbd2677c8> in <module>()
     10     batch_size = 16,
     11     epochs = 10,
---> 12     callbacks = [checkpoint]
     13 )


NotImplementedError:

Comment: Please update the question accordingly, and don't post further questions in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this tutorial on Text classification using BERT: https://pysnacks.com/machine-learning/bert-text-classification-with-fine-tuning/

It has working code on Google Colab(using GPU) and Kaggle for binary, multi-class and multi-label text classification using BERT.

Hope that helps.

Comment: hlw, do you have any git link or colab link?

Comment: yes, for Binary Text Classification: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14b2rbIgwhQ1BI-zkyiMjQv-jV85xj9tf , for Multi-class Text Classification: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VuPv_SInihZIO9gwy1p0YqYQy76bwBuS, for multi-label text classification: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1UEnLAFs1Hrr1NCCQ2Apu5CtRZSK4DHDi

Answer (score -2):

1. You need to use gpu.
2. Try this=

with torch.no_grad():